# If $S$ is nonsingular then $\mathop \cap \limits_S G({S^{ - 1}}AS) = \sigma (A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,S \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ and $S$ is nonsingular, and $\sigma (A)$ is spectrum of  matrix $A$, and $G(M)$ denotes the union of all Gerschgorin discs of a matrix $M$.

Why is $\mathop  \cap \limits_S G({S^{ - 1}}AS) = \sigma (A)$ true?

Comment: What do you mean by *"G(S^{-1}AS) is Gersgorian disk"*? Do you mean that $G(M)$ denotes the ***union*** of all Gerschgorin discs of the matrix $M$?

Comment: @ user1551 - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By similarity, we may assume that $A$ is already in its Jordan form. Let $S_\epsilon=\operatorname{diag}(1,\epsilon,\epsilon^2,\ldots,\epsilon^{n-1})$ with $\epsilon>0$. Then $G(S_\epsilon^{-1}AS_\epsilon)\subseteq\mathop\cup\limits_{i=1}^n B(\lambda_i(A), \epsilon)$, where $B(z,r)$ denotes the closed ball of radius $r$ centered at $z$. When $\epsilon\to0$, $G(S_\epsilon^{-1}AS_\epsilon)$ shrinks to $\sigma(A)$. Hence $\sigma(A)=\mathop\cap \limits_{\epsilon>0}G(S_\epsilon^{-1}AS_\epsilon)$. Since $\sigma(A)=\sigma(S^{-1}AS)\subseteq G(S^{-1}AS)$ for every nonsingular $S$, we conclude that
$$
\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathop\cap \limits_SG(S^{-1}AS)
\subseteq\mathop\cap \limits_{\epsilon>0}G(S_\epsilon^{-1}AS_\epsilon)=\sigma(A).
$$